# ASCX User control SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, ascx

I'm pretty new to Tridion 2011 and I need to create a simple ASCX control to implement an ASP.NET dinamically generated DropDownList.
I'm a little bit confused about how to create a Compound Template (should I do it?) and a Dynamic Assembly to reach my purpose.
I've created a Component Template with output ASCX Web Control and set it to "Published as a Dynamic Component" but I can't figure out how to add my code behind to it.
Should I publish a specific .ascx.cs page and reference it in my .ascx or is there a more "Tridion" way to do it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest you post this over at http://tridion.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a post that may help with this:
 http://tridionnut.blogspot.com/2013/01/tridion-and-net-user-controls.html

Also keep in mind that the answer above is something you will want to keep in mind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may have more on https://tridion.stackexchange.com/

However, I strongly suggest that you don't publish .NET code directly from any CMS. This will introduce performance issues and other risks to your application. It would be better to put your code in a DLL which is deployed as part of your web application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've already posted a question on tridion.stackexchange and I'll keep in mind your suggestion about DLLs.